# React Native Jest Error: ReferenceError: Headers is not defined

Tags: react-native, jestjs, redux-toolkit, react-native-testing-library

I'm using React Native with redux-toolkit
When I'm trying to run jest I get this error:
[image]

"jest": "^29.2.1",
"@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.8.6",

Comment: This is not really enough information to go on. But you probably should mock your api calls that are exported by RTK query. Doing api calls in unit tests is not a good idea